# Summarize values in strings in one variable based on positions of related values in another variable

Tags: r, dplyr, sapply

I have this type of data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  A_aoi = c("C*BB*B", "C*B*C*", "B**", "C*B"),
  A_dur = c("234,312,222,3456,1112,77", "12,13,14,15,11,1654", "896,45222,55", "5554,322,142"),
  B_aoi = c("**ACC", "AC*", "AAA", "C*A*"),
  B_dur =c("12,13,15,100,100", "14,55,66", "88,99,100", "1,2,3,4")
)
```

What I need to do is summarize in columns `A_dur` and `B_dur` those values with the same *position* in the string as the run-length duplicates in columns `A_aoi` and `B_aoi`.

Now 'positons' can be captured by indices, which is why I split the strings in all columns first:

```
library(stringr)
df[,c(1,3)] <- lapply(df[,c(1,3)], function(x) str_split(x, ""))
df[,c(2,4)] <- lapply(df[,c(2,4)], function(x) str_split(x, ","))
```

Then I get the indices of run length duplicates in columns `A_aoi` and `B_aoi`:

```
library(dplyr)
df$index_A_aoi <-  sapply(df$A_aoi, function(x) which(x == lead(x)))
df$index_B_aoi <-  sapply(df$B_aoi, function(x) which(x == lead(x)))
```

Now when I try to summarize values in `A_dur` and `B_dur` based on indices in `index_A_aoi` and `index_B_aoi` with `sapply`, I get stuck:

```
sapply(as.numeric(df$A_dur), function(x) x[df$index_A_aoi] + lead(x[df$index_A_aoi]))
Error in lapply(X = X, FUN = FUN, ...) : 
  'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

**Expected result**:

```
df
   A_aoi                A_dur B_aoi     B_dur
1 C*BB*B 234,312,3678,1112,77 **ACC 25,15,200
2 C*B*C*  12,13,14,15,11,1654   AC*  14,55,66
3    B**            896,45277   AAA       287
4    C*B         5554,322,142  C*A*   1,2,3,4
```

I'm open to and grateful for any solutions including a `dplyr` one.

Comment: Sorry forgot to accept your answer, works well! Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution taking help of data.table's `rleid` function

```
library(data.table)

calculate <- function(p, q) {
  mapply(function(x, y) toString(tapply(as.numeric(x), rleid(y), sum)), 
      strsplit(p, ','), strsplit(q, ''))
}

aoi_cols <- grep('aoi', names(df))
dur_cols <- grep('dur', names(df))
df[dur_cols] <- Map(calculate, df[dur_cols], df[aoi_cols])
df

#   A_aoi                    A_dur B_aoi       B_dur
#1 C*BB*B 234, 312, 3678, 1112, 77 **ACC 25, 15, 200
#2 C*B*C* 12, 13, 14, 15, 11, 1654   AC*  14, 55, 66
#3    B**               896, 45277   AAA         287
#4    C*B           5554, 322, 142  C*A*  1, 2, 3, 4
```

`calculate` function takes a pair of columns split `dur` on comma and `aoi` on every character and use `rleid` to create groups of consecutive occurrence of value and `sum` them. We apply `calculate` function for all such pairs in the dataset.